# Azure Signalr Serverless Managment SDK Send to group does not work

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I am using azure signalr serverless mode with [Management SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md)  and have REST Api wrapper to integrate with my other application.

I can broadcast messages to all clients but struggling with sending to specific group. I am Negotiating like this

```
`ServiceHubContext.NegotiateAsync(new NegotiationOptions() { UserId = _userId, Claims = new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, _userId),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _userId),    
                }`
```

and adding user to group

```
 ServiceHubContext.UserGroups.AddToGroupAsync(_userId, GroupName);
```

and sending message to group

```
ServiceHubContext.Clients.Group(GroupName).SendAsync("locked", lockModel)
```

But message is still received by all users.

I also tried to add connectionId to specific group but still does not work.
please note Rest Api does not have any authentication implemented.

I am hanging from last 2 month on this issue and unable to get any workaround for serverless mode. please help